# rails 5 and font awesome icon inside an input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, font-awesome

I'm having a hard time to set an icon inside my input in my `form_for` in rails 5! 
i already tried many different ways to do it but nothing is working

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name,  class: "form-control" do %>
    <%= fa_stacked_icon "twitter", base: "square-o" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I would like to know how can i do to set the icon inside my input
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need CSS to do it, here's how:

1. Go [here](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) and get the unicode value of the icon you want.
2. Add it as either `value` or `placeholder` attribute to your `input` using `raw` method (otherwise it will output the code).
3. Style your `input` with `"font-family: 'FontAwesome';"`.

For example (using `stack-overflow` code `&#xf16c;`):

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", value: raw("&#xf16c;"), style: "font-family: 'FontAwesome';" %>
</div>
```

And you're good to go; check the snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<input type="text"
       value="&#xf16c;"
       style="font-family: 'FontAwesome';"/>
```

Comment: its working but just as a placeholder i would like something that stay permanent in the input field
with another versions of rails i made a "do block" and everything runs smooth but i dont know whats happening with this version

Comment: @ElmerAPerez Could you show the code you are using? I just updated the answer using `value`. It should work as in the snippet (also tested on rails 5).

Comment: @ElmerAPerez What is the output you are getting?

Comment: thanks for your help but when i set the "value:" if i press the delete button the icon goes away

Comment: im gonna upload it to github and you can check it out whats wrong and thanks in advance

Comment: @ElmerAPerez I understand what you want to do now. Why not simply put the icons outside the inputs? Will be much more easier (and you could style them for a better user experience). You could even add icons next to your select inputs.

Comment: I wanted to do that like the last resource! Because I know I can do it easily with the font-awesome helper and set it up in a do block... now I don't know what's happening!

Comment: The behavior is normal, its just more text (the same will happen if you just add plan text to `value` or `placeholder`. It can be done, but it will no be that simple, you will either need javascript/jQuery or more complex CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

This will keep the icon visible in the beginning of the text box:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><%= fa_icon "twitter" base: "square-o" %></span> 
        </div>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
</div>
```